# find numbers x,y,z that achieve maximum possible value of $E(x,y,z) = \alpha(x-y)^2 + \beta(y-z)^2 + \gamma (z-x)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be positive real numbers and let $[a,b]$ be an interval. Find numbers $x,y,z\in [a,b]$ so that $E(x,y,z) =  \alpha(x-y)^2 + \beta(y-z)^2 + \gamma (z-x)^2$ is maximum.

I think we can assume WLOG that $\alpha \leq \beta\leq \gamma.$

> But how would one justify the above assumption?

Also, I think one can assume $x\leq y\leq z$.

> As for the justification, under the assumption that $x\leq y\leq z,$ one can see that $E(x,y,z) \ge E(y,x,z)$ and $E(x,y,z) \ge E(z,y,x).$ But $E(x,y,z) - E(z,y,x) = (\alpha - \beta)((x-y)^2 - (y-z)^2),$ and it's not clear that this value is nonnegative (if one only makes the above two additional assumptions).

With the above two assumptions, note that a convex function on a bounded interval attains its maximum at one of the endpoints. It might be useful to define a function like $f_1(y) = \alpha(y-a)^2 + \beta(y-b)^2,$ which can be used to maximize $E(a,y,b)$ where $y$ ranges over $[a,b]$. But must the maximum value of $E$ be obtained at a point of the form $(a,y,b)$ or $(b,y,a)$?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum is attained with two of $x, y, z$ at the endpoints $a, b$. Because if one or both of the endpoints are not used, suppose $x \le y \le z$ (same proof with other orders), then
$\alpha (x-y)^2 \le \alpha(a-y)^2$,
$\beta (y-z)^2 \le \beta(y-b)^2$,
$\gamma(z-x)^2 \lt \gamma(b-a)^2$,
so $E(x,y,z) \lt E(a,y,b)$.

We assume w.l.o.g. that $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$.
We compare $E$ of all permutations of $x,y,z$. Note that permuting $(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to permuting $((x-y)^2, (y-z)^2, (z-x)^2)$.
It is a known result that the maximum sum of term-by-term product of two finite sequences is when they are ordered the same way ([Proof for two sequences producing the maximum value when sorted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355250/proof-for-two-sequences-producing-the-maximum-value-when-sorted)).
So $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$ implies $(x-y)^2 \le (y-z)^2 \le (z-x)^2$ for the maximum.
As two of $x,y,z$ must be $a,b$, this implies $\{x,z\}=\{a,b\}$.
We can choose $x=a, z=b$ as we obtain the same value for $E$ by symmetry: $E(a,y,b)=E(b,a+b-y,a)$.

Then to get the optimum value for $y$, study $\frac {\partial E(x,y,z)} {\partial y} = 2\alpha(y-x)+2\beta(y-z) = 2\alpha(y-a)+2\beta(y-b)$.
This is null for $y_0$ such that $\alpha(y_0-a)=\beta(b-y_0)$, $y_0=\frac {\alpha a + \beta b} {\alpha+\beta}$.

$\frac {\partial^2 E(x,y,z)} {\partial y^2} = 2\alpha+2\beta > 0$, so $\frac {\partial E(x,y,z)} {\partial y}$ is a strictly increasing function of $y$ that is null on $y_0$.
$E(a,y,b)$ is a decreasing then increasing function of $y$, that reaches a minimum on $y_0$.
There are 2 local maxima, one on $a$ and one on $b$. The largest one is for $y=a$:
$E(a,a,b)-E(a,b,b)$
$=\alpha(a-a)^2+\beta(a-b)^2+\gamma(b-a)^2-\alpha(a-b)^2-\beta(b-b)^2-\gamma(b-a)^2$
$=(\beta-\alpha)(a-b)^2 \ge 0$.

In summary, maximum is attained at $x=a,y=a,z=b$.
(I don't detail the other solutions. There is the symmetric one at $(b,b,a)$; plus some other permutations of $(a,a,b)$ and $(a,b,b)$ when there are some equalities between $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Those other solutions have the same maximum value of $E$).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why we can assume WLOG that $x\leq y \leq z$ and $\alpha \leq \beta \leq \gamma$? Is it just some other ordering gives a similar proof?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "permuting $(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to permuting $((x-y)^2, (y-z)^2, (z-x)^2)$"?

Comment: @user3379 I only assume wlog that $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$. For $x, y, z$, we know that the maximum is attained if $(x-y)^2, (y-z)^2, (z-x)^2$ have same ordering as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. This means either $x \le y \le z$, or $z \le y \le x$. But then we can choose $x \le y \le z$, because solutions are symmetrical, i.e. $E(x,y,z)=E(z,x+z-y,x)$.

Comment: @user3379 "Permuting $(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to permuting $((x−y)^2,(y−z)^2,(z−x)^2)$" means there is a bijection between the set of permutations of $(x,y,z)$ and set of permutations of $((x−y)^2,(y−z)^2,(z−x)^2)$, and each permutation of one set corresponds to one permutation of the same variables in the other set. Example, if you pose $z_2=y, y_2=z$ (which permutes $y$ with $z$ in $(x,y,z)$), then $((x−y_2)^2,(y_2−z_2)^2,(z_2−x)^2) = ((x−z)^2,(z−y)^2,(y−x)^2)$: compared to $((x−y)^2,(y−z)^2,(z−x)^2)$, this has permuted $(x-y)^2$ with $(x-z)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on a geometrical interpretation. One can object that it is not fully rigorous, but its interest is to give a "big picture" of this issue.

First of all, we are concerned by the range of function $E$, i.e., the set of values of $m$ such that

$$E(x,y,z)=\alpha(x-y)^2 + \beta(y-z)^2 + \gamma (z-x)^2=m\tag{1}$$

has a solution $(x,y,z)$. We are going to see that it is an interval: $m \in (0,M)$, the "restricted issue" being to find for which $(x,y,z)$ one obtains extremal value $M$.

First of all, equation (1) is that of a cylinder $(C_m)$ with axis directed by $(1,1,1)$. Indeed, this is the equation of a quadric surface invariant by any translation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

(i.e., if we replace $x,y,z$ by $x+t,y+t,z+t$ resp., equation (1) is left unchanged)

Remark: Cylinder $(C_m)$ belongs to the family of elliptical cylinders (the other categories, hyperbolic or parabolic cylinders being ruled out due to the fact that $E(x,y,z)$ is a positive definite expression). An elliptical cylinder has an elliptical normal cross section.

The constraint on $x,y,z$ has, as well, a geometrical interpretation

$$(x,y,z) \in \underbrace{[a,b]^3}_{(B)}$$

where $(B)$ is a cube. One of the great diagonals of $(B)$, joining vertices $(a,a,a)$ and $(b,b,b)$, is also directed by vector $(1,1,1)$.

The constraint is that cube $(B)$ must meet $(C_m)$.

As cylinder $(C_m)$ is "inflating" when $m$ increases, it intersects the cube till a certain limit value of $m$ which is reached when the "last" vertex of cube $(B)$ among

$$(a,a,b),(a,b,a),(b,a,a),(b,b,a),(b,a,b),(a,b,b)$$

is just "touching" the cylinder. Please note that we don't consider $(a,a,a)$ and $(b,b,b)$ : they "stay in place" on the diagonal directed by vector $(1,1,1)$.

Moreover, this issue has a symmetry due to the fact that the center of the cube:
$$\Omega\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$ is a center of symmetry for the cube and for the cylinder. As

$$\begin{cases}(a,a,b) \ \text{and} \ (b,b,a)\\
(a,a,b) \ \text{and} \ (b,b,a)\\
(a,a,b) \ \text{and} \ (b,b,a)\end{cases} resp.$$

are symmetrical with respect to $\Omega$ (said otherwise, their midpoint is $\Omega$), we need only consider 3 vertices, for example:

$$\{(a,a,b),(a,b,a),(b,a,a)\}\tag{2}$$

Final answer: considering (2), as

$$\begin{cases}E(a,a,b)&=&(\beta+\gamma)(a-b)^2\\E(a,b,a)&=&(\alpha+\beta)(a-b)^2\\E(b,a,a)&=&(\alpha+\gamma)(a-b)^2\end{cases}$$

the maximum is reached in the following vertices:

$$\begin{cases}
(a,a,b) \ \& \ (b,b,a) \ \ \text{if} \ \ \beta+\gamma \ge \alpha+\beta, \alpha+\gamma  \ \ \iff \ \ \alpha \le \beta,\gamma\\
(a,b,a) \ \& \ (b,a,b) \ \ \text{if} \ \ \alpha+\beta \ge \beta+\gamma,\alpha+\gamma  \ \ \iff \ \ \gamma \le \alpha,\beta\\
(b,a,a)  \ \& \ (a,b,b)\ \ \text{if} \ \ \alpha+\gamma \ge \alpha+\beta,\beta+\gamma   \ \ \iff \ \ \beta \le \alpha,\gamma \end{cases}$$

(with the meaning $p \le q,r \iff p \le q \ \ \& \ \ p 
 \le r$)

---

**A remark:** Quadratic form $E(x,y,z)$ has

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha+\gamma&-\alpha&-\gamma\\
-\alpha&\alpha+\beta&-\beta\\
-\gamma&-\beta&\beta+\gamma\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

as its associated matrix ; in particular vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}$  can be interpreted as an eigenvector of $Q$ associated with eigenvalue $0$, otherwise said, a basis of the kernel of $Q$.

But beyond that, using linear algebra doesn't look
the right approach.

Comment: I like your answer (I like geometry). Perhaps you could add at the end that, depending upon the comparison between $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, the maximum will be reached on $(a,a,b)$, or $(a,b,a)$, or $(b,a,a)$, but only one of these 3 points (plus the symmetrical point), if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are all different. Which is also due to geometry.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni Thanks. I have followed your advice by giving explicitly the vertices according to the dominant values among $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Comment: @user3379 Any comment ?